# eclipse can't open Console Window in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

The eclipse version is Mars.1 Release(4.5.1).
I have a problem about eclipse.
When I  click Show View -> Console,I see the Console Window is opened,and it close at once.
I'm try to reset layout(click Window->perspective-> reset...),but it is invalid.
How can I open it? 
reinstall eclipse？（I don't like this way）

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList$BasicIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=3, size=0)

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList$BasicIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=3, size=0
 at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList.add(AbstractEList.java:334)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.reconcileManagerToModel(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:927)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.ActionBars.updateActionBars(ActionBars.java:114)

Comment: I can't analyse the log. Can I delete ./metadata to solve the problem?

Comment: I delete the  ./metadata to solve the problem,but it appear in Window ->Show View ->Other->general .I  hope that it appear in Window->Show View.